# Broken link in stackexchange.com About Us page (no more team)

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, broken-link

In the [About Us page](https://stackexchange.com/about), there is link titled "[Meet our Team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team)":

> [image]

However, Stack Overflow no longer expose their list of employees (reason is clear and out of scope here), so the link is essentially broken, leading to a totally different page with no team in there.

Please remove the dead link from that page.